# ReferenceError: finishedAjax is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to create a registration form, and I am using AJAX to check if the e-mail address entered has already been used, but every time I check, I get the error 'ReferenceError: finishedAjax is not defined' This is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Loading').hide();
        $('#email_address').blur(function () {
            var a = $("#email_address").val();
            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
            if(filter.test(a)) {
                $('#Loading').show();
                $.post("check_email_availablity", {
                    email: $('#email_address').val()
                }, function(response) {
                    $('#Loading').hide();
                    setTimeout("finishedAjax('Loading', '"+escape(response)+"')",400); 
                });
                return false;
            }
        });

        function finishedAjax(id, response) {
            $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
            $('#'+id).fadeIn();
        }
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    finishedAjax('Loading', escape(response));
}, 400);
```

Comment: Actually this does seem like a better idea, it works the same and can keep the finishedAjax function within the document.ready block, but now... on the console it tells me if the email is available or not but on the actual page the loader just keeps going round, any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Your **finishedAjax** function must be outside of **document.ready** block